# using kendo.template (external template) in KendoUI MVC Grid ClientTemplate (column)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to use an external template in a column's ClientTemplate like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Project>().Name("Projects")
    .Columns(cols =>
    {
        cols.Bound(m => m.LetterNumber);
        cols.Bound(m => m.CityName);
        cols.Bound(m => m.OrganName);
        cols.Bound(m => m.DateString);
        cols.Bound(m => m.EngineersCount);
        cols.Bound(m => m.ExpertTypeString);
        cols.Bound(m => m.ProjectId)
            .Title("")
            .ClientTemplate("#buttonsTemplate(data)#");
    })
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax().Read("GetList", "Projects"))
)
```

```javascript
<script type="kendo/x-template" id="buttonsTempate">
    #switch(State){
    case 0:#
        <a href="@Url.Action("SelectEngineers")?pid=#=ProjectId#">انتخاب مهندسین</a>
    #break;
    case 1:#
        <a href="@Url.Action("Print")?pid=#=ProjectId#">چاپ نامه</a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("SelectEngineers")?pid=#=ProjectId#">انتخاب مهندسین</a>
    #break;
    }#
</script>

<script>
    var buttonsTemplate = kendo.template($("#buttonsTempate").html());
</script>
```

But I get an empty column.

If I use internal (inline) template, it works fine:

```javascript
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Project>().Name("Projects")
    .Columns(cols =>
    {
        cols.Bound(m => m.LetterNumber);
        cols.Bound(m => m.CityName);
        cols.Bound(m => m.OrganName);
        cols.Bound(m => m.DateString);
        cols.Bound(m => m.EngineersCount);
        cols.Bound(m => m.ExpertTypeString);
        cols.Bound(m => m.ProjectId)
            .Title("")
            .ClientTemplate(
                "#switch(State){case 0:#"
                 + "<a href='" + @Url.Action("SelectEngineers") + "?pid=#=ProjectId#'>انتخاب مهندسین</a>"
                 + "#break;case 1:#"
                 + "<a href='" + @Url.Action("Print") + "?pid=#=ProjectId#'>چاپ نامه</a>"
                 + "<a href='" + @Url.Action("SelectEngineers") + "?pid=#=ProjectId#'>انتخاب مهندسین</a>"
                 + "#break;}#");
    })
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax().Read("GetList", "Projects"))
    .DoConfig()
)
```

But I prefer external template for such a long template. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to put the templates into an editor template (View/Shared/EditorTemplates)?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. besides, does server template work with ajax binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external templates created by `kendo.template()`, are in fact functions with a `data` input parameter. So in your template you should prepend all your columns with a `data.` e.g.:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SelectEngineers")?pid=#=data.ProjectId#">
```

Also, in the grid options, you should use the `#=` syntax in order to see the output:

```
.ClientTemplate("#=buttonsTemplate(data)#")
```